# Unable to mount Internet Manager ZTE MF-195 USB wireless modem

Tags: wireless, mount, network-manager, usb-modem

I just got this ZTE MF-195 USB wireless modem, and when I plug it in I get this message:

```
Unable to mount Internet Manager
Error mounting: mount: /dev/sr0 already mounted or /media/Internet Manager busy
```

The results of running `lsusb` are:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b25f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd   
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth Controller  
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 19d2:1514 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM   
X1:~$  dmesg | grep tty   
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled  
[    1.019341] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x50b0 (irq = 19) is a 16550A
```

...so my device is `Bus 003 Device 005: ID 19d2:1514 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM`.

What should I do?

Comment: You should be able to compile the latest sakis3g on Ubuntu now. Just follow the Debian/Ubuntu step in the README file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with usb 3g internet sticks on linux before and got it working using sakis3g. Give it a try!

https://github.com/Trixarian/sakis3g-source

Comment: hi,i tried to do so but it seams i am missing some libraries
./compile 
Base directory:  /home/r/Downloads/sakis3g-source-master.
Source files:    All found.  
Device database: Found and transformed.  
/tmp/ccOjkdz9.o: In function `main':  
usb_modeswitch.c:(.text+0x191f): undefined reference to `usb_init'  
usb_modeswitch.c:(.text+0x1934): undefined reference to `usb_set_debug'  
usb_modeswitch.c:(.text+0x1939): undefined reference to `usb_find_buss...

Comment: i managed to instal it but i get message:
Failed to connect

Comment: also nm-tool does not show it... any suggestions

Comment: ok i managed to mount my usb at least but what i get is just a a folder withall subsequent files in my /media/Internet Manager

Comment: When I used sakis3g it was pretty straight forward, it recognized my usb stick, asked me some info, password and connected. There are some posts on the net about this modem if you want to take a look http://www.linux.org/threads/zte-lte-usb-modem-not-connecting.4491/ but I also found a bug report and people say it could be a kernel issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1173566 in that case you could try with the latest ubuntu version eventually.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using a precompiled copy of sakis3g. The current source code doesn't compile on all version of Ubuntu - especially since usb_modeswitch moved to using libusb1.

Try grabbing the copy I have @ http://trixarian.net/sakis3g.gz

Comment: Then how to compile it?